# Pasar matrices por funciones en lenguaje C

Tags: c, matrices

Lo que sucede es que no sé porque no funciona esta parte del código...

Al momento de llamar a mi función `PideDatos` la matriz que genero con los números aleatorios sigue guardada al momento de llamar a mi función `EscribeDatos`.

```
int main(void) {
    int C, Dimension;
    float Sistema[Tam][Tam], Inversa[Tam][Tam];
    PideDatos( & Dimension, Sistema);
    printf("\n\n\nLa matriz es: \n\n");
    EscribeDatos(Dimension, Sistema);
    Invierte(Dimension, Sistema, Inversa);
    printf("\n\n\nLa inversa de la matriz es: \n\n");
    EscribeDatos(Dimension, Inversa);

    printf("\n\n\nLa identidad es: \n\n");
    EscribeDatos(Dimension, Sistema);
    scanf("%d");

    return 0;
}

void PideDatos(int * Dim, float Sist[][Tam]) {
    int A, B;
    srand(time(NULL));

    printf("\nPROGRAMA QUE CALCULA LA MATRIZ INVERSA, DADA SU\n");
    printf("DIMENSI%cN (RELLENADA CON N%cMEROS ALEATORIOS)", 224, 163);

    printf("\n\n\nIntroduzca el tama%co de la matriz:", 164);
    scanf("%d", & * Dim);

    for (A = 1; A <= * Dim; A++)
        for (B = 1; B <= * Dim; B++) {

            Sist[A][B] = rand() % 16;
        }
}

void EscribeDatos(int Dim, float Sist[][Tam]) {

    int A, B;
    for (A = 1; A <= Dim; A++) {
        for (B = 1; B <= (Dim); B++)
            printf("%7.2f", Sist[A][B]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Según tenia entendido lo que se hace en las funciones se queda en las funciones y no debería tener datos para la matriz. Gracias.

Comment: Traslado tu código para testar y da fallos por todas partes. A ti te funciona? Qué valor tiene Tam.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema de ese código? ¿Qué resultado muestra? ¿Qué resultado esperas?

Comment: `for (A = 1; A <= * Dim; A++)` Las matrices en C están indexadas desde 0. Un bucle típico podría parecer como `for (a = 0; a < *dim, ++a)`.

Answer (score 1):

> Según tenia entendido lo que se hace en las funciones se queda en las funciones y no debería tener datos para la matriz. Gracias.

Si, no, a veces, depende.

De hecho, en tu propio código ya contradices tu afirmación:

```
int main(void) {
    int C, Dimension;
    float Sistema[Tam][Tam], Inversa[Tam][Tam];
    //            ^^^  ^^^           ^^^  ^^^ <--- Tam no es de, ni se queda en la función main
    // …
    return 0;
}
```

Tienes un  problema de falta de conocimiento, no entiendes el ciclo de vida de los datos ni cómo compartir datos entre diferentes partes del programa. Te presento a los...

### Punteros.

Un puntero es un tipo de dato que apunta a otro dato. Imagínalo como la matricula de un coche, la matrícula te apunta al vehículo pero obviamente la matrícula no es el vehículo.

Mediante el puntero, puedes pasar información a otras partes del programa (técnicamente conocido como ámbito), observa este ejemplo:

```
void multiplica_por_dos(int *valor) {
    *valor *= 2;
}

int main(void) {
    int veintiuno = 21;
    multiplica_por_dos(&veintiuno);
    //                 ^ <--- Operador '&' obtiene el puntero a la variable.

    printf("%d", veintiuno); // Muestra 42.

    return 0;
}
```

Como puedes ver, la variable `veintiuno` no pertenece al ámbito de la función `multiplica_por_dos` y sin embargo dicha función ha hecho cambios en esa variable, cambios que han persistido tras finalizar la función.

En [c](/questions/tagged/c) las formaciones<sup>1</sup> se convierten implícitamente a puntero al primer elemento de la formación, en caso de formaciones de dos dimensiones<sup>2</sup> éstas se convierten a puntero a la primera formación (es decir, puntero a puntero). Por lo tanto, igual que en el ejemplo de `multiplica_por_dos`, con el puntero puedes modificar datos que pertenecen a otro ámbito y estos cambios persisten fuera de dicho ámbito.

---

- <sup>1</sup>También conocidas como *arreglos*, o en inglés *arrays*.
- <sup>2</sup>A veces llamadas *matrices*.